# file upload form is not posting anything

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, file

I have a file upload form, here it is:

```
<form action="./wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="edit-profile-field" id="edit-profile-pic-wrap">
            <h1 class="profile-descriptor" id="edit-username-label">Public Picture Upload</h1>
            <div id="profile-pic-border">
                <?php get_avatar(get_current_user_id(), 225); ?>
            </div>
            <input type="file" name="edit-pic[file]" id="pic-upload" size="225">
            <input id="edit-pic-submit" type="submit" name="edit-pic-submit" value="Upload New Avatar">
        </div>      
    </form>
```

The form posts to the following script:

```
if(isset( $_POST['edit-pic-submit']) ) {
    echo "000";
}
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["error"]);
print_r($temp);
```

The script has the following output:

Array ( [0] => )

I just can't figure out why nothing is being posted. Thanks in advance

Comment: plz print_r( $_FILES ) first and check

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($_FILES);`? What does it show?

Comment: You cant use $_FILES['file'] as you have different name in field

Comment: You named your file 'edit-pic[file]', therefore you are trying to access a file that has not been Posted with $_FILES['file']

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone, it is working now. Learning every day!